# Get image value total

Tags: c#, image

Below is my code:

```
private double GetImageValue(Bitmap Image)
{
    double ImageValue = 0;

    for (int X = 0; X < Image.Width; X++)
    {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < Image.Height; Y++)
        {
            Color CurrentPixel = Image.GetPixel(X, Y);

            ImageValue += CurrentPixel.A + CurrentPixel.B + CurrentPixel.G + CurrentPixel.R;
        }
    }
    return ImageValue;
}
```

The following code returns the total value of each pixel in the image. Is there a way to speed up the procedure? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitmap data is stored in an unmanaged GDI object. Every time you call [`GetPixel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) the system needs to access this object. You can speed it up by using [`LockBits`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) to directly access the raw image data.

```
private double GetImageValue(Bitmap image)
{
    double imageValue = 0;

    // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
    var bmpData = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Get the address of the first line.
    var ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
    var bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * image.Height;
    var values = new byte[bytes];

    // Copy the RGB values into the array.
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, values, 0, bytes);

    // Add the rgb values to ImageValue
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
    {
        int lineStart = y * Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width * 3; x++)
        {
            imageValue += values[lineStart + x];
        }
    }

    // Unlock the bits.
    image.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return imageValue;
}
```